# how to write sql query to laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

i have a sql query like this and i want to convert it to laravel how i can do it?

i have try it, but i confusing on `wherein` and `join`

sql query

```
SELECT MIN(StartFrom) as StartFrom,MAX(EndTo) as EndTo from appointmentsettings 
WHERE day=1 
and PersonID IN (
    SELECT p.id
    FROM users p
        JOIN appointmentsettings aps ON p.id = aps.PersonID 
    WHERE p.active=1 AND aps.CompanyID = 1 OR aps.PersonID IN(
        SELECT cps.user_id 
            from companypersonstructs cps
            WHERE cps.CompanyID =1          
    )  group by aps.PersonID        
)
and active=1
```

here what i try

```
Appointmentsetting::select('StartFrom', 'EndTo')
->min('StartFrom')
->max('EndTo')
->where(['Day'=>$day, 'Active'=>1])
->whereIn('PersonID', function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->select('p.id')
          ->from('users as p')
            $query->join('appointmentsettings as aps', 'p.id', '=', '')
        ->where(["user_id" => $id, 'Active' => 1])->get();
        })->orderBy('id')->get();
```

Comment: Have you tried DB Raw Query?

Comment: What would you achieve if you "convert" it to Laravel? Query builder will construct the same query as you have. Just use `DB::select()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Appointmentsetting::select('StartFrom', 'EndTo')
    ->min('StartFrom')
    ->max('EndTo')
    ->where(['Day'=>$day, 'Active'=>1])
    ->whereIn('PersonID', function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->select('p.id')
            ->from('users as p')
            ->join('appointmentsettings as aps', 'p.id', '=', '')
             ->where(["user_id" => $id, 'Active' => 1]);
        })->orderBy('id')->get();
```

You have an error in your join inside the function. Try the above code.

Also you must use `get()` only at the end of the query and not inside the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

DB Query way

```
DB::table('appointmentsettings')->join('users','p.id','=','')
->select(DB::raw('MIN(StartFrom) as StartFrom','Max(EndTo) as EndTo'))
->where([['user_id',$id],['Active','1']])
->groupBy('appointmentsettings.PersonID)
->orderBy('id','ASC')
->get();
```